# Sorting list of tuples by first element of each tuple - Python 2.7

Tags: python

I have a list of tuples:

```
lst = [('Q4-2005', 327.93), ('Q1-2005', 133.05), ('Q3-2005', 500.95), ('Q2-2005', 254.22)]
```

I want to sort this list by the first element of each tuple. Thus my resulting, sorted list should look like:

```
[('Q1-2005', 133.05), ('Q2-2005', 254.22), ('Q3-2005', 500.95), ('Q4-2005', 327.93)]
```

I tried doing this using sorting() and lambda, but the resulting list is not sorted. Im thinking its because my 'dates' are actually strings:

```
sorted(lst, key = lambda x: x[0])
```

So i guess I have 2 questions..

First, How do I sort the list of tuples so that they are in chronological order?

Second, what is the best way to make python realize that 'Q1-2005' is a date? Eventually I want to plot this data where x-axis is the 'date' and y-axis is the number associated with each date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You said that you want Python to interpret `Q1-2005` as a date. If you convert the list to such a format, then sorting becomes trivial, and plotting will also be easier. Here's one way to do it using `datetime.date` (it encodes the quarters as a date representing the first date of the quarter).

```
from datetime import date

# date() takes in year, month, day args
date_lst = [(date(int(q[3:]), 3 * int(q[1]) - 2, 1), v)
            for q, v in lst]
```

This will result in something like this:

```
[(datetime.date(2005, 10, 1), 327.93),
 (datetime.date(2005, 1, 1), 133.05),
 (datetime.date(2005, 7, 1), 500.95),
 (datetime.date(2005, 4, 1), 254.22)]
```

After that, sorting chronologically is as simple as `sorted(date_lst)`.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this, redefining a sort, would be to make a new class or a new function. The default sort algorithms in Python use traditional lexicographical sorting. Calling sort(tuple) will sort them in alphabetical/alphanumeric order, but not necessarily the order you want.

I will note, sorting by default will sort the tuples based on their index [0] value, only going to index [1] if two first indices are the same.

Answer (score 1):

dont name your variable list!!!

```
sorted(the_list, key=lambda x: list(reversed(map(int,x[0][1:].split("-")))))
```

Comment: fixed I had to call list on the reversed iterator ... good example of why not to name your variable list

Comment: Multiple exclamation marks? Hrm, Terry Pratchett has something to say about those.. :-P

Comment: pep8 suggests no spaces around the `=`

Comment: I really really really wanted to make my point!!! all these poor variable names make me question my sanity :P

Answer (score 0):

Using an object with `__lt__` and/or `__cmp__` would be good, but if you want to use a key function:

```
#!/usr/local/cpython-3.3/bin/python

list_ = [('Q4-2005', 327.93), ('Q1-2005', 133.05), ('Q3-2005', 500.95), ('Q2-2005', 254.22), ('Q1-2006', 123.45), ('Q2-2007', 678.90), ]

def key(element):
    subresult1 = element[0]
    subresult2 = subresult1.split('-')
    subresult2.reverse()
    subresult2[0] = int(subresult2[0])
    return subresult2

list_.sort(key=key)
print(list_)
```

Which out for the years - they're more significant than the quarters.